# Want to send user to another page onCLick in react, but not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So i am trying to route my user to next page on clicking the item. To do this I am using react router dom's Link. But on clicking it is not taking me to the desired page. SO please check it out and help me.

The code of my App.js and the current files are also given below.

And also the Hii is printed but the link is not working.

App.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import AppNavbar from './components/appNavbar';
import Login from './components/login';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import FacultyMain from "./components/facultyMain";
import ImageUpload from './components/imageUpload';
import StudentMain from './components/studentMain';
import SubjectAssignments from './components/subjectAssignments';

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                <BrowserRouter>
                <AppNavbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                        <Route path='/facultymain' component={FacultyMain} />
                        <Route path='/studentmain' component={StudentMain} />
                        <Route path='/subjectassignments' component={SubjectAssignments} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Current pages code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

class StudentMain extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem onClick={() => {
                        console.log("Hii");
                        <Link to="/subjectassignments" />
                    }}>3IT401 - Cryptography and Network Security</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IC401 - Management and Economics</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>4OE395 - OE I data Visualization and Interpretation</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT402 - Data Mining</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT413 - PE Deep Learning</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT451 - Open Source Software Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT452 - Software Testing and Quality Assurance Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT453 - Data Mining Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT454 - Project</ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default StudentMain;
```

package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "virtual-lab",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

class StudentMain extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroupItem onClick={() => {
                        
                        this.props.history.push('/subjectassignments'); 
                        
                    }}>3IT401 - Cryptography and Network Security</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IC401 - Management and Economics</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>4OE395 - OE I data Visualization and Interpretation</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT402 - Data Mining</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT413 - PE Deep Learning</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT451 - Open Source Software Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT452 - Software Testing and Quality Assurance Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT453 - Data Mining Lab</ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem className="btn" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>3IT454 - Project</ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default StudentMain;
```

Refer: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

Comment: Yes this works thank you. But whats the problem with the Link tag ?

Comment: `<Link>` just a UI element which creates the `<a>` tag with that link.